# Phantomjs fail but test works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have a simple test using the selenium-webdriver javascript package that finds a text field by name and enters text.  The test runs fine in Firefox and Chrome, but fails in Phantomjs.  I also tried finding the element by xpath and id, but it keeps failing in Phantomjs.  Has anyone had a similar experience and could point me in the right direction for debugging?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that phantom actually navigated to the page in question.

Comment: What's the best way to verify that in phantom? Should I look for another element like the title?

Comment: Did you solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. In my case, problem was that we have self signed certificate on our test server. I found solution here: [phantomjs-and-self-signed-certificates](http://andrewgorton.uk/blog/selenium-ghostdriver-phantomjs-and-self-signed-certificates/)
You have to set desired capabilities for your driver:

```
 DesiredCapabilities dCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dCaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    dCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[]{"--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes"});
    dCaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dCaps);
```

To ignore self signed certificates set "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes"

Comment: Please summarize the link in question and edit your answer with the information accordingly. Also it looks like it is Java code. Do you also have a solution for the JavaScript language bindings?

Comment: Rather than simply link to external sites, can you please quote the appropriate parts of the link and *then* link.  This avoids the answer "rotting".